# 500 Error caused by !="" check

Tags: php

Im getting an 500 Error when running this code:

```
    foreach($services as $service)
    {
        if(isset($service['value'] and $service['value']!=""))
        {
            echo $service['service']." = ".$service['value']."<br/>";
        }
    }
```

When i remove this part: `and $service['value']!=""`
of the initial IF,
The error is gone.
But i need this check to be sure im not inserting empty values into the Database.
I also tried the is_null() function but im still getting the error.
By the way, the Echo is just for debugging, it is not going to be in the finished code
I dont really know what is causing this Error... Maybe someone can help me here ;)

Comment: Did you mean to evaluate `$server['value'] !=""` rather than `isset($server['value'] != "")`

Comment: `if( !empty( ... ) )` would be better in this instance anyway, IMO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a matter of parentheses:

```
if(isset($service['value']) and ($service['value'] != ""))
```

You were trying to test isset of an `AND` condition, which cannot be done. You have to test `isset()` *then* test value.

Comment: Ok thanks, I completely overlooked this bracket :D
I know that i can not test isset of an and condition, i just missed that the bracket was closed behind the != and not behind the value to check :)